# Universal image loader without sampling

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I want the image from url as it is without being sampled, but while using nostra's universal image loader the image is getting sampled. How am I supposed to avoid this is there any option  to be included for this?

Comment: just coment out the sampling code!! it should be something like        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }
            
            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;-- coment this

Answer (score 1):

Enable `imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)` in display options (`DisplayImageOptions`).